# Unzip a bunch of zips into their own directories

Tags: linux, unzip

I have a bunch of zip files I want to unzip in Linux into their own directory. For example:

a1.zip
a2.zip
b1.zip
b2.zip

would be unzipped into:

a1
a2
b1
b2

respectively. Is there any easy way to do this?

Comment: This belongs on superuser or serverfault

Answer (score 14):

Add quotes to handle spaces in filename.

```
for file in *.zip
do
  unzip -d "${file%.zip}" "$file"
done
```

Comment: This doesn't work on filenames with spaces. Jefromi's answer does.

Answer (score 12):

```
for zipfile in *.zip; do
    exdir="${zipfile%.zip}"
    mkdir "$exdir"
    unzip -d "$exdir" "$zipfile"
done
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for x in $(ls *.zip); do
 dir=${x%%.zip}
 mkdir $dir
 unzip -d $dir $x
done
```

Comment: You just barely beat me, but enough differences I posted anyway - you don't need to use ls (the globbing will expand just fine on its own), you don't need `%%` (it deletes the longest match, and there's only one possible match, picky, I know), and it's always good to quote your filenames!

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for contributing to an old post, this works in cmd line for me and it was a life saver when I learnt about it

```sh
for file in $(ls *.zip); do unzip $file -d $(echo $file | cut -d . -f 1); done
```

Hey presto!

Comment: Did not confirm this works but a oneliner is convenient for me.