# how to unzip a zip file inside another zip file?

Tags: shell, unix, zip, unzip

I have multiple zip files inside a folder and another zip file exists within each of these zip folders. I would like to unzip the first and the second zip folders and create their own directories.
Here is the structure

```
Workspace
    customer1.zip
      application/app1.zip
    customer2.zip
      application/app2.zip
    customer3.zip
      application/app3.zip
    customer4.zip
      application/app4.zip
```

As shown above, inside the  `Workspace`, we have multiple zip files, and within each of these zip files, there exists another zip file `application/app.zip`. I would like to unzip `app1`, `app2`, `app3`, and `app4` into new folders. I would like to use the same name as the parent zip folder to place each of the results. I tried the following [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2463947/10912827) but this unzips just the first folder.

```
   sh '''
        for zipfile in ${WORKSPACE}/*.zip; do
            exdir="${zipfile%.zip}"
            mkdir "$exdir"
            unzip -d "$exdir" "$zipfile"
        done
                
    '''
```

Btw, I am running this command inside my Jenkins pipeline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No idea about `Jenkins` but what you need is a recursive function.

## recursiveUnzip.sh

```
#!/bin/dash
recursiveUnzip () { # $1=directory
    local path="$(realpath "$1")"
    for file in "$path"/*; do
        if [ -d "$file" ]; then
            recursiveUnzip "$file"
        elif [ -f "$file" -a "${file##*.}" = 'zip' ]; then
            # unzip -d "${file%.zip}" "$file" # variation 1
            unzip -d "${file%/*}" "$file" # variation 2
            rm -f "$file" # comment this if you want to keep the zip files.
            recursiveUnzip "${file%.zip}"
        fi
    done    
}
recursiveUnzip "$1"
```

Then call the script like this

```
./recursiveUnzip.sh <directory>
```

In you case, probably like this

```
./recursiveUnzip.sh "$WORKSPACE"
```